# How to show data of a team in reports and dashboard?

Tags: custom-report-type, custom-reports, report-chart

I have requirement of showing data of a team in reports and dashboard. See the attached Image -
[image]

In this Image, 20, 18, 20, 18 is record count of records created by each Manager. I am able to plot the same graph to show the records created by Users whose role is Manager but my requirement is that each bar show the record count of all the roles who reports to Manager. For example, Let's assume three Sales representative work under the Manager1, so the bar should show the record count data by adding the each sales representative record -> Manager1(Record Count) = Sales Rep1 + Sales Rep2 + Sales Rep3.

Here, If Manager creates any record its record should also be summed up -> Manager1(Record Count) = Manager1 + Sales Rep1 + Sales Rep2 + Sales Rep3

Can anyone suggest me how to achieve this requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @parvaz May I know, Is that record creator and owner fields are same in your org? OR the report results are showed only based on the `CreatedBy.user` value?

Comment: Hi @MohanrajSivalingam, record creator and owner fields are same in my org.

Answer (score 0):

If the "Record owner" and "Record Creator" means, Please do the following actions,

- Create the report for that object to show all the users (Both Managers and Sales Reps) records.
- Create a bucket with field source as " Owner" field and create new bucket value with "owner name" and add the sales rep's and his manager into that bucket as values (Repeat for each manager and his group) .

Once it's done it's show the record count as you're described **Manager1(Record Count) = Manager1 + Sales Rep1 + Sales Rep2 + Sales Rep3** once after you're grouped the report records using this created bucket in point #2.

Note: When a new user adding into any team.. you need to update this bucket (add that user into appropriate bucket) to get the up to date results.

Since it's somewhat having manual works but I think it's one of the way to achieve what you're requested.

Hope it helps.